# When using Vuex, am I meant to stick to one store or do I want to have multiple stores for different logic?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Currently I'm figuring out Vuex and my store has started becoming quite big with many actions. Am I meant to separate different logic in different stores? For example, 1 store that would contain all authentication logic and another store for game play logic ( if I'm making something like a game ), etc? Or should I just stick everything into one store?

If I were to make more stores, how should I name them ( so that I am following a convention )?

Is there anything else I'd need to know if I were to split the logic into more than one stores?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only use a single store, but you can (and in your case should) use  modules.

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html

Note the namespacing option that you can use to resolve naming conflicts

Comment: Thanks, that's really useful. I'll select this as an answer as soon as I can.